# how to clear oled display in micropython

Tags: python, esp8266, micropython

I'm doing this on esp8266 with micro python and there is a way to clear OLED display in Arduino but I don't know how to clear display in micropython i used [ssd1306](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RuiSantosdotme/ESP-MicroPython/master/code/Others/OLED/ssd1306.py) library to control my OLED

and this is my error I've written a code that prints on OLED from a list loop, but OLED prints it on the text that was printed before it (print one on top of the other not clear and printing) 7[image]

```
display = [ip, request_uri, country, region, city]

for real_time in display:
  oled.text(real_time, 0, 20)
  oled.show()
  time.sleep(2)
  print(real_time)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `fill()` method is used to clean the OLED screen:

```py
oled.fill(0)
oled.show()
```